# How to make chaijs assertions noop (disable assertions)

Tags: node.js, chai

I am using chaijs in a nodejs service & wanted to disable all assertions in the release build to check their perf impact.

Is there any setting to do that?

Answer (score 0):

One possible way to do that is to set an environment variable to check if the build is a "release" build. If it is, then just don't run the assertions. E.g.:

```
if (process.env.RELEASE_BUILD) {
    // no assertions
}
```